# ExpandableListView: make groups make non-selectable in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, expandablelistview, contextual-action-bar

My problem is - I've got an `ExpandableListView` and want to use `Contextual Action Bar (CAB)` on it's child items. The bad thing is - the group items are also get selected by long-click, which is bad for me. So is there any way to make them non-selectable while in ActionMode?
I tried to use `onItemLongClick`; tried onLongClick inside `getGroupView`. Tried some other tricks but failed.

If you find this impossible - maybe there is a way to make all the child items within the selected group be selected as well? That could be a solution, but I could not do that niether.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
What I did is the next:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id,
                        boolean checked) {
    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id);
    if (checked && type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        elvBankBranches.setItemChecked(position, false);
            return;
        }
}
```

When item is checked - I check if it is a grouop - and if it is - just uncheck it. Works fine.
Note! - when uncheck the item in code - this method `onItemCheckedStateChanged` will be triggered once again!

Hope it helps someone )